# How to make my token in private network exchangeable?

Tags: tokens, private

I am recently creating a token in my private network and want my DAPP users to exchange the token within the network. But at any point of time, i want my users to exchange the tokens they have for real ether or any other currency. Is it possible if my token lives in my private network?

I know that moving my token to main network will solve. But i want my users to transact within my private network, and at some point if they want to exchange the token for another token or ether they need to do so

Comment: That was to move my token to main network for exchanging. Now my question is, how can i exchange a token in private network for some ethers in main network

Comment: You can't trade private network tokens for real network Ethers

Comment: So if i have my tokens in my private network, what is the best possible way to exchange that token for any other token in main network or even for any fiat currency, how can i monetize my token?

Comment: Umm. Tokens are not miracle moneymakers. If someone is willing to pay for your tokens then you can sell them. Otherwise they have no explicit value.

Comment: You'd need to have a pool of existing ether that you can release to your token holders as they trade their token into for real ether. This is a peg system similar to how rootstock works. Obviously, this is a 3rd party software acting a middleman between the two chains.